# How to automate pdf print popup in firefox browser using selenium?

Tags: selenium, firefox

I'm trying to automate following overlay using selenium. I have tried robot class and actions class but seems not working. Please help me.

[image: Find attached screenshot]

Comment: You can't do this with selenium alone. alternatively you can use Robot API. with robot API you can't check whether the print popup is opened or not, but you can perform desired actions on the popup through shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot automate this with selenium, because selenium is used for web applications. If you want to automate non-web applications, you can use for this case [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or other non-web testing software.

Answer (score 1):

Please show your try with robot framework.

If you use tab and enter, you can select ok button. You just have to test how many tab events you have to press, before you focus the ok button

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);


robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..I have used this code & it works fine.

```
         public void VerifyClickToDownload()
         {
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='downloadPdf']")).click();
              Thread.sleep(5000);
             //Operation on save pdf pop up
              Robot robot= new Robot(); 
              robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
              robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
              robot.delay(6000);

       }

        public void VerifyDownload() throws AWTException, InterruptedException
        {

         Robot robot = new Robot();
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_J);
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         System.out.println("pdf is downloaded.");  
        }
```